# How to localStorage properly with one name?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to use localStorage["something"] = item; but the script is loaded in every page, which creates files like:

> http_www.google.bg_0.localstorage
>
> http_stackoverflow.com_0.localstorage`

I want the current webpage data to be stored in one file, just like the normal extensions do. But I found that this is possible only while localStorage is accessed from popups.html. Then the outputted file is like:

> chrome-extension_cognfheolmcnfppokallnahdaibbaabe_0.localstorage

Does somebody knows how to do that? Or maybe how to use the localStorage from popup.html, without showing it?

---

**EDIT:**

When I try to use a function from the background.html like:

> chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().setItem("currentWord",s);

Nothing gets called, whu could this happen?

Here's my background.html:

---

```
     <html><head><script>

     var logging  = false;

     function setItem(key, value) {
          alert("Saving setting");

          try {
             log("Inside setItem:" + key + ":" + value);
             window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
             window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);
          } catch(e) {
             alert("Error inside setItem: " + e);
          }
     }

     function clear() {
              window.localStorage.clear();
     }

     function log(txt) {
              if(logging) console.log(txt);
     }

     </script></head></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put values to a local storage inside a background page. In order to do that you need to pass your value there from a content script using [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/messaging.html).